# How to resize Excel column width using ImportExcel

Tags: excel, powershell, format

I downloaded Excel report but I need to resize some of the columns to different width using PowerShell so I'm just wondering how can I achieve that. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

For Example, I want to modify User, Date & Time, Item column to width size 30, Activity Column to width size 50 and some other column to width size 30 so on...

```
function Modify-Columns {

    $params = @{
        AutoSize      = $true
        # TableName     = 'exampleTable'
        TableStyle    = 'Light9' # => Here you can chosse the Style you like the most
        BoldTopRow    = $true
        WorksheetName = "Audit Log"
        PassThru      = $true
        Path          = "C:\AuditLogSearch\$((Get-Date).AddDays(-7).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')) _ $(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd") Audit-Log-Records.xlsx" # => Define where to save it here!
    }

    Write-Host "Start Modifiying Column and Row using AD DisplayName and Excel Files"

    $modifiedFile = Import-Csv "C:\AuditLogSearch\Modified-Audit-Log-Records.csv"
    $actionReference = Import-Csv "C:\AuditLogSearch\Reference\eDiscovery_Activities_List.csv"

    $result = foreach ($u in $modifiedFile) {
        $u.User = (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $u.User).DisplayName
        New-Object PsObject -Property @{
            User                      = $u.User
            # "Search Criteria"         = $u."Search Criteria"
            "Result Status"           = $u."Result Status"
            "Date & Time"             = $u."Date & Time"
            "Search Conditions"       = $u."Search Conditions"
            "SharePoint Sites"        = $u."SharePoint Sites"
            "Exchange Public Folders" = $u."Exchange Public Folders"
            "Exchange Mailboxes"      = $u."Exchange Mailboxes"
            "Case Name"               = $u."Case Name"     
            "Search Criteria"         = $u."Search Criteria"
            "Item"                    = $u."Item"
            
            "Activity"                = if (($actionReference | where-object { $_.Name -eq $u."Activity" }).Value -ne $null) { ($actionReference | where-object { $_.Name -eq $u."Activity" }).Value }
            else { $u."Activity" }
        }  | Select-object -Property User, "Date & Time", "Case Name", "Item", "Activity" , "SharePoint Sites", "Exchange Mailboxes", "Exchange Public Folders" , "Search Criteria", "Result Status"
    }
    
    $xlsx = $result | Export-Excel @params
    $ws = $xlsx.Workbook.Worksheets[$params.Worksheetname]
    $ws.View.ShowGridLines = $false # => This will hide the GridLines on your file
    Close-ExcelPackage $xlsx

    Write-Host "Finished Modifiying Column and Row using AD DisplayName and Excel Files"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may have seen, the `-AutoSize` is not very exact, it tends to leave more width than needed. In case you need to set a hardcoded value to one of the columns you can use:

- `$xlsx.Workbook.Worksheets['SheetName'].Column(n).width = newVal`

**NOTE:** This method requires the use of `-PassThru`.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
$result = [pscustomobject]@{
    Col1 = 'Test'
    Col2 = 'Test'
    Col3 = [datetime]::Now
}

$params = @{
    AutoSize      = $true
    TableStyle    = 'Light9'
    BoldTopRow    = $true
    WorksheetName = "Audit Log"
    PassThru      = $true
    Path          = './test.xlsx'
}

$xlsx = $result | Export-Excel @params
$ws = $xlsx.Workbook.Worksheets[$params.WorksheetName]

# This is how you can get the number of Columns, Index starts from 1 not 0.
$ws.Dimension.Columns           # => 3
$ws.Column(1).Width             # => Col1 current Width is 9.140625
$ws.Column(1).Width = 5         # => Updated to 5
$ws.View.ShowGridLines = $false # => Hide the GridLines
Close-ExcelPackage $xlsx
```